# zend framework 2, paginator with join

Tags: php, join, pagination, zend-framework2

I'm writing with zend framework 2, but I have a problem when I use pagination with join.
I've this function:

```
            if ($paginated) {       
                $select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select ();
                $select->from ( 'cliente' );
                $select->columns ( array ('*'), false );
                $select->join ( 'privato', "cliente.idCliente = privato.idCliente", array ('*'), 'left' );
                $select->join ( 'azienda', "cliente.idCliente = azienda.idCliente", array ('*'), 'left' );

                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet ();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype ( new Cliente () );
                $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect ( 
                        $select, 
                        $this->tableGateway->getAdapter ()); 
                        $resultSetPrototype );
                //$paginatorAdapter = $this->tableGateway->selectWith ( $select );
                $paginator = new Paginator ( $paginatorAdapter );
                return $paginator;
            }

            $select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select ();
            $select->from ( 'cliente' );
            $select->columns ( array ('*') );
            $select->join ( 'privato', "cliente.idCliente = privato.idCliente", array ('*'), 'left' );
            $select->join ( 'azienda', "cliente.idCliente = azienda.idCliente", array ('*'), 'left' );

            $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith ( $select );
            return $resultSet;
```

the code outside the if statement works correctly, the internal code no. Gives me this message:

```
            Statement could not be executed (42S21 - 1060 - Duplicate column name 'idCliente')
```

where is the error?
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
$select->columns ( array ('idCliente1'=>'idCliente'), false );
```

is because you have to provide an alias, or on the join, you can ignore the idCliente by defining all the columns name you want like:

```
        $select->join ( 'azienda', "cliente.idCliente = azienda.idCliente", array ('column1','column2','etc..'), 'left' );
```